# Python set to array and dataframe

Tags: python

**Interpretation by a friendly editor:**

I have data in the form of a set.

```
import numpy as n , pandas as p
s={12,34,78,100}
print(n.array(s))
print(p.DataFrame(s))
```

The above code converts the set without a problem into a numpy array.
But when I try to create a DataFrame from it I get the following error:

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

So is there any way to convert a python set/nested set into a numpy array/dictionary so I can create a DataFrame from it?

---

**Original Question:**

I have a data in form of set .
Code

```
 import numpy as n , pandas as p
 s={12,34,78,100}
 print(n.array(s))
 print(p.DataFrame(s))
```

The above code returns same set for numpyarray  and DataFrame constructor not called at o/p . So is  there any way  to convert python set , nested set into numpy array and dictionary ??

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: @RoyShahaf see edit

Answer (score 5):

Pandas can't deal with sets (dicts are ok you can use `p.DataFrame.from_dict(s)` for those)

What you need to do is to convert your `set` into a `list` and then convert to `DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd

s = {12,34,78,100}
s = list(s)
print(pd.DataFrame(s))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list(s):

```
import pandas as p
s = {12,34,78,100}
df = p.DataFrame(list(s))
print(df)
```

Comment: Hello sir !! I'm still not getting the error , data frame constructor not called properly .

Comment: @Therii if you are NOT getting the error, then whats the problem?

Comment: My apologies! My original answer assumed s was a dict, when it is a set. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to convert it to a list first? [The DataFrame() method accepts data which can be iterable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). [Sets are iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

```
dataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(yourSet)
```

This will create a column header: "0" which you can rename it like so:

```
dataFrame.columns = ['columnName']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as n , pandas as p

s={12,34,78,100}

#Create DataFrame directly from set 
df = p.DataFrame(s)

#Can also create a keys, values pair (dictionary) and then create Data Frame, 
#it useful as key will be used as Column Header and values as data
df1 = p.DataFrame({'Values': data} for data in s)
```